# Do I have to return TwiMl when I receive a callback from Twilio?

Tags: c#, .net, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

When we get an inbound text from Twilio (via a callback endpoint),  **are we required to return TwiMl?**

**This is what our controller looks like, which works fine:**

[image: Twilio Endpoint]

We have no use for replying and generating messages as they come in automatically and would like to just let Twilio know that the call was successful.

When I try to return a 201 status code or an application/json response, we get the following warning in the Twilio console:

[image: Twilio console warning]

Their documentation is all over the place and almost implies that you HAVE to reply with TwinMl - is this this the case or is there another way to respond without generating the warning above?

Comment: Instead of using a screenshot, please include the code as a code snippet in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to reply with TwiML, but an empty (TwiML) response, as mentioned in your question, is also valid. There's no need to respond with a text message.

Answer (score 0):

To further elaborate on what @IObert said. You can respond with Messaging TwiML or plain-text to respond to the message, but you don't have to. You can respond with an empty HTTP response, or an empty TwiML response:

```xml
<Response></Response>
```

The latter is what your code should be doing, but based on the Twilio error it seems the HTTP response is JSON instead of XML (TwiML). I cannot see in your code why this would be the case.

Could you show us what the HTTP response headers and body looks like?